# CalDAV/CardDAV Radicale backup

Tags: bash, backup, carddav, radicale

Now that I am runing Radicale on my own Linux server (to manage calendars and contacts), I am trying to figure out how to backup Addressbooks via a bash script (which I could then cron or manually launch).

The exporting part is not going to be so difficult thanks to Duplicity.

But where the ... is located the Addressbook ?
There is no *.vcf related to Radicale anywhere on my system.

Comment: How is that even remotely a programming question?

Answer (score 1):

I've found it.
It is in located in the personal directory :
~/.config/radicale/collections/contact/AddressBook.vcf

In ~/.config/radicale/collections/contact you there are as well the calendars.

Hum. This seems to me to be (remotly) a programing question, since its answer is  program for who want to program its own bash backup script.